# I am unable to run the flutter app on a physical device, it says its already installed but it's not

Tags: flutter

> Failed to install D:\Flutter Projects\meals_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure
> [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.example.meals_app signatures do not match previously installed version

This is the error message that pops up:

[image: screenshot]

I was actually following a course and made this app. few days before I had installed this on my physical device, it was working perfectly. Then I uninstalled it, and now when I try again, I get this error

Comment: uninstall the old apk from your phone and then run ``flutter run``

Comment: Please provide the code by pasting rather than screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [ADB Command-line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line)? If not [install](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) this then uninstall the app with adb using:

```
  adb uninstall com.example.app (your app id)
```

I think this will help.